# Facing error while trying to run dynamic pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Hope you're doing well 
I'm new to PL/SQL and I'm trying to write a dynamic PL/SQL.
What I've written so far is :

```
declare

   sql_stmt     varchar2(100);
   v_student_id number := 1;
   v_new_stname varchar2(50);

begin

  sql_stmt := 'update student 
               set student_name = ''pantea'' where student_id :1 ' ||
              'returning student_name into :2';
  execute immediate sql_stmt
  using v_student_id
  returning into v_new_stname;

     dbms_output.put_line('New student name is :' || v_new_stname);

end;
```

when I want to run the code I see this error :

```
ORA-06502:Numeric or value error:Character string buffer too small.
```

I'm 80 percent sure that the problem might be in this part of the code

```
set student_name = ''pantea''
```

but I don't know how to solve it and I could not also find it on oracle books
I know how to handle this in T/SQL but have no idea how to handle this in PL/SQL.

Comment: I see no reason for dynamic SQL. I advise you don't make things too complicated for yourself.  Also, the `q'[]'` notation helps when you need to woute single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the comparison operator for the WHERE clause

If you really want to use dynamic SQL (which is not needed for a simple UPDATE statement like that), then you should also pass **all** values as parameters, not just the student ID.

```
declare
   sql_stmt     varchar2(100);
   v_student_id number := 1;
   v_name varchar2(20) := 'pantea';
   v_new_stname varchar2(50);
begin
  sql_stmt := 'update student set student_name = :1 '|| 
              'where student_id = :2 '|| 
              'returning student_name into :3';

  execute immediate sql_stmt
    using v_name, v_student_id
    returning into v_new_stname;

  dbms_output.put_line('New student name is: ' || v_new_stname);
end; 
/
```

---

The "string buffer too small" seems to happen when you are continuing a string literal (constant) over multiple lines. So it's better to open and close the string constants on each line and concatenate them using `||` rather than embedding a new line in the string as you did.